# How do you iterate through an amalgamation of two Enumerables efficiently?

Tags: ruby, arrays, performance

Given

```
a = nil # or [1,2]
b = [1,2] # or nil
```

Can you iterate through the concatenation of `a` and `b` without allocating an intermediate or creating massive amount of boiler plate code?

```
# meaning do this much more efficiently
((a || []) + (b || [])).each do |thing|
  # more lines here 
  puts thing
end
```

This is kind of ugly:

```
l = lambda{|thing| do_my_thing }
a.each{|thing| l.call(thing)} if a
b.each{|thing| l.call(thing)} if b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you're willing to create a container (which should be cheap even if the elements contained are large), you could:

```
[a,b].compact.each do |e|
  e.each do
    # stuff
  end
end
```

You do have to create a container array, but since you don't have to copy the contents of the sub-arrays (and instead are just dealing with two array pointers), it should be very quick and not terrible on the GC.

An alternate solution might just be to create a method:

```
def multi_each(*args,&block)
  args.each do |a|
    a.each(&block) if a
  end
end

multi_each(nil,[1],[2,3]) do |i|
  puts i 
end
# 1
# 2
# 3
```

Comment: actually a multi iterate seems fine that could be crafted

Comment: It's worth noting that *args is coerced into an array, and explicit block passing has a performance cost associated with it (http://blog.sidu.in/2007/11/ruby-blocks-gotchas.html#.UFK9uLXA9Ro) so the second form may not be more performant than the first.

Comment: good point! I guess doing this in a c extension would be slight overkill

Comment: If you absolutely have to have maximum performance, then you want to drop to C, yes. However, Enumerator iteration is already implemented in C, and the original solution of using a wrapper array shouldn't really impose too much overhead. If that's not fast enough though, ruby-inline might get you the performance you need without the hassle of writing a full-blown extension.

Comment: Why  not `[a, b].compact.flatten.each` instead of the two nested `each` calls? Seems to be enough for what OP asked.

Comment: I presume the OP asked for something without an intermediary for performance reasons based on the assumption that the data in `a` and `b` may be nontrivial; flatten copies all non-nil values into a new array. If the source arrays are large, this could have a detrimental performance impact.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using 1.9, I would use the ability for multiple splats:

```
a = nil
b = [1, 2]
[*a, *b]
#=> [1, 2]

a = [3, 4]
b = nil
[*a, *b]
#=> [3, 4]
```

So `[*a, *b].each {}` seems exactly like what you want.

Comment: that is really handy, I assume it does cause one extra allocation though

Comment: It does, but I try not to let considerations like that influence clean code until it's proven to be a bottleneck.

Comment: to be honest I prefer it as well, only concern is lack of support on 1.8 for the gem I am working on I really want to keep that

Comment: Please let 1.8 finally die! It's been years since 1.9 was released and there will be no more 1.8.7 releases, 1.8.7-p330 was the last one.

Comment: If you really want to keep 1.8 support, I'd go for `[a, b].compact.flatten.each {}` btw.

Answer (score 1):

What you have can be made far more concise and considerably less ugly by passing the lambda as the block itself:

```
l = lambda { |thing| do_my_thing }
a.each(&l) if a
b.each(&l) if b
```